# call 2 methods from JSmethod lightning synchronously

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningjs

I have 3 methods and i want to call and execute 2 methods in 3rd method one by one. Help apprecited.

```
    saveaccountExclusion : function(component, event, helper) {
        **//somethinghere**
    },
    openModalPopup : function(component, event, helper) {

     component.set("v.isOpen" , 'true');
    },
    saveAndNewPopup : function(component) {
        **I want to call saveaccountExclusion  and openModalPopup synchronously**
    }
```

Comment: Are you making apex server calls in the 2 methods?

Comment: You can't make callouts synchronously. This has severe performance implications. Instead, you will want to make a Promise chain to call each in order. There's other answers on this site that demonstrates that; just search for Promise in the search bar.